# What's your idea about transcript? Is it important?

Tags: java

I visiting this site and I am eager to apply for the Master’s or ph.D's program at the University.

I want to go computer science faculty(java) or development but I have a question.

Do you consider your transcript(s) of university-level work an accurate indication of your academic ability? (what's your Idea?)

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: I don't know why my question is closed? my question is related to computer science and developing so why?
I am deeply disappointed from this behavior and I have no idea how to track this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean what classes you have taken, transcripts are at least an indicator of what concepts and technologies you have some experience of.

If it is actual computer related work, as I see it, they are not as important. The work you are able to get as a student, and then do in your spare time to earn some extra cash, might not be what you like to do or excel at.